# Localization of quotient of polynomial ring over integral domain

Tags: commutative-algebra

I'm now reading Eisenbud's, Commutative Algebra, p.132~133, Nullstellensatz, General form.

My question is,

Q. Let $R$ be a integral domain and $Q$ a prime ideal of $R[x]$, and $S:=R[x]/Q$.

Let $0\neq b:=g+Q \in S$ be a nonzero element and $K$ the fraction field of $R$.

Then the localization $S[b^{-1}]$ is isomorphic to $K[x]/QK[x]$ ?

This question originates from following underlined statement.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Since localization commutes with quotient, $S[b^{-1}] \cong R[x][b^{-1}]/Q[b^{-1}]$. But this ring is isomorphic to $K[x]/QK[x]$?

My first attempt to construct such an isomorphism is $(1/b^{n})f(x) + Q[b^{-1}] \mapsto (1/b^{n})f(x) + QK[x]$. This map is well defined but I stucked at showing injectivity.

Or is there any other way to show the isomorphism?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133934/discussion-on-question-by-plantation-localization-of-quotient-of-polynomial-ring).

Comment: Is  the above $QK[x]$  a really prime ideal of $K[x]$ ? If so, why?